# Limit a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

Sorry for perhaps a newbie question but I haven't found an answer on the web.

I have textarea. I want to have it resizeable as it is, but I want it to have a specific size when I open the page at the start. That size should be the minimum size of the textarea. Also, I want it to have a maximum size when I expand it, but both the widgh and the height should be resizeable.

For example: the textarea's size should start and be minimum H:300px and W:300px. It should be resizeable to maximum H:600px and W:700px. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css to the textarea:

```
textarea {
  min-height:300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: No problem at all :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to demonstrate! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/e344c5f1/5/

```
textarea {
  /* Define your minimum size here */
  min-height:300px;
  min-width: 300px;

  /* Define your maximum size here */
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

Don't forget to set the overflow for the containing elements to avoid hiding or overlapping, depending on what you want (check the fiddle for an example of hiding).